# Sub Dataframe creation from the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, slice

I am facing a real struggle. I want to filter for a particular event but want to explore also events around that filtered event.

Implicit example:

I want to filter Dataframe for days when stocks opened with gaps. When event is identified I want to create chart to see how the stock traded when that particular event happened so I need data pre and post event.

And here I am stuck I do not know whether to create additional column in which I will Boolean for the even I am looking for or if there is any other more elegant solution to do so.

Appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Post what code you have tried so far. Some example data and expected output.

Comment: Please give a data example or code to start.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as wb

data = wb.DataReader('spy', 'yahoo', start='1/1/1978', end='30/10/2019')
data['Change'] = data['Close'].pct_change() * 100
data['Gaps'] = ((data['Open'] - data['Close'].shift(1))/data['Close'].shift(1)) * 100
data['Performance during day'] = ((data['Close'] - data['Open'])/data['Open']) * 100
data = round(data, 2)
filtered_data = data[data['Gaps'] > 2]
print(filtered_data)
```